# Saving double without losing precision

Tags: objective-c, ios, double

In the app I'm building now I use some really small numbers(`4.12027703723203E-18`, `7.685842358296843E-21`, `6.882072376426952E-24`, `2.7150860398820128E-27`, etc).

The problem is that when I'm storing them into the array they become 0. A bit of code:

```
-(BOOL)checkNewInfo:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath andValue:(double)value {
  //code omitted
  [self.theValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", value]];
  //code omitted
}
```

I did some debugging and here's the result:

```
(gdb) p (double) value
$1 = 4.12027703723203e-18
(gdb) po [self theValues]
<__NSArrayM 0x6a45dc0>(
1.6086921836575816E-11,
3.7511646463463610E-13,
0.000000,
4.6856843535196843E-21,
9.820723621786952E-24
)
```

The initial numbers are there from a text file and they can be easily accessed and used.

So I replaced the number at index 2(old `5.12027703723203E-18`, new `4.12027703723203E-18`). So in theory the number shouldn't change, but in reality it becomes `0.000000`.

What should I do in order to keep the numbers?

Thank you, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `%e` or `%E`.  %f always prints in a 0.00000 format

Answer (score 2):

You are formatting the during using `%f`, so the output is `0.00000`.

You should use `%e` instead, or even `%.16e` if you want to keep 16 digits precision.

```
[self.theValues replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.16e", value]];
```

Answer (score 2):

1.) Don't store the values as string, but as NSNumbe or better,

2.) Use NSDecimalNumber (128bit floating point)

Answer (score -1):

Your only option is to store the numbers in their binary format.